# How to take the running time for counting the inversions in an array 10 times?

Tags: java

calculate the average time of executing the algorithm for
different array sizes. The array sizes you should use are 5000, 10000, 15000, …, 50000. For
each different array size, you must execute the algorithm 10 times, each time using a different array of random integers (each integer can be from 1 to 10 times the array size). You will then
take the average time over the 10 executions, and that will be running time for arrays of that
size. Here’s a sample pseudocode:

```
NUMEXPS = 10
for n in 5000, 10000, …, 50000
totalTime = 0
for i in 1 … NUMEXPS
A ← new array of n random integers (from 1 to 10*n)
startTime ← get current time
inversions ← Sort-and-CountInv(A)
endTime ← get current time
totalTime ← totalTime + (endTime – startTime)
print n, totalTime / NUMEXPS
```

I created the array with the randoms integers in the main, I couldn't figure out my counting inversions class is counting the inversions correctly but I am having trouble implementing the running time. This is what I have tried with the running time.

```
static int mergeSort(int arr[], int n) 
{ 
    int temp[] = new int[n];
    return _mergeSort(arr, temp, 0, n - 1, n); 
} 

/* An auxiliary recursive method that sorts the input array and 
  returns the number of inversions in the array. */
static int _mergeSort(int arr[], int temp[], int left, int right, int n) 
{ 
    int mid, inv_count = 0; 
    if (right > left) { 
        /* Divide the array into two parts and call _mergeSortAndCountInv() 
       for each of the parts */
        mid = (right + left) / 2; 

        /* Inversion count will be sum of inversions in left-part, right-part 
      and number of inversions in merging */
        /*long startTime = System.nanoTime(); 
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) { */
        inv_count = _mergeSort(arr, temp, left, mid, n); 
        inv_count += _mergeSort(arr, temp, mid + 1, right, n); 

        /*Merge the two parts*/
        inv_count += merge(arr, temp, left, mid + 1, right); 
    } 
        /*long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long totalTime = startTime - endTime; 
        
    }*/

    return inv_count; 
    
}
```

I put the `long starTime = System.nanoTime();  long endTime = System.nanoTime(); long totalTime;`  and `for()` loop

in commented code because it kept the program in an infinite loop.

This is the code that creates the array, this code is in my main tester

```
Scanner myInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number for your array:");
        int inputNum = myInput.nextInt();
        
        while(inputNum != 0) {
            n *= NUMEXPS;
            inputNum--;
        }
        
        Random rand = new Random();
        int tempArr[] = new int[n];
        int randInt = rand.nextInt(n);
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr.add(rand.nextInt(n));
            tempArr[i] = arr.get(i);
            System.out.print(tempArr[i] + " " + "\n");
            
        }
```

this line of code is what I used to prove that it works.

```
System.out.print("Inversions Counted:" + countRandNums.mergeSort(tempArr, n));
```

Comment: What is your question? Which part of the code you are facing the problem with, I did not understand that?

Comment: I'm trying to get the running time when the mergeSort method starts counting inversions, the part is where it says long startTime = System.nanoTime(); till totalTime = startTime - endTime / 10. Thanks for the edit, didn't know about the pseudo code, my english is not perfect, not my first language.

Comment: That's the part it's giving me an infinite loop, I have to run a simulation of the code 10 times and see it's running time.

Comment: Try with a smaller value of n. say when `n=5`. Put `System.out.println` at more places where you think it has gone into an infinite loop. Once you have the code working for a smaller value of n, you can increase n as per your pseudo code.

Comment: If i enter `n = 5` my array will be 10^5 big with random numbers from 0-10^5. It's supposed to be big so i can see the running time of the inversions counted.